# Should I move my project files into the parent directory after starting a project in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

After I run `django-admin.py startproject foobar` it creates a parent `foobar` directory and another `foobar` (same name) folder within that, along with the `manage.py` file. The question is - should I move all of the files from `/foobar/foobar` into `/foobar`, and just delete the redundant directory? What is the reason this structure is there in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [new project layout](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160124184903/https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py) is there to remove sys.path hackery inside manage.py script and to eliminate nasty bugs with imports that lead to executing some code, like signal handlers, many times instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project):

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

- The outer `mysite/` directory is just a container for your project. Its name doesn't matter to Django; you can rename it to anything you like.
- `manage.py`: A command-line utility that lets you interact with this Django project in various ways. You can read all the details about `manage.py` in `django-admin.p`y and `manage.py`.
- The inner `mysite/` directory is the actual Python package for your project. Its name is the Python package name you'll need to use to import anything inside it (e.g. `import mysite.settings`).